# NodeJS + Redis + HTTP Get

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, redis

I'm currently getting data from my database by the way of PHP using Nodejs.
The problem is that the script that I want to execute after grabbing datas is actually executing directly after the instance of my grabing function and I get everytime an error saying that my datas are undefined.

Here is my code :

```
var http = require('http'),
redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();

        client.on("error", function (err) {
          console.log("Error " + err);
        });

        var sessionData;
        // Check if we have session create with sessionID gived before (hash)

        client.get('sessions:'+sessionId, function (err, result) {
            var resData;
            //Check if we have session with the session id 
            // If we have not execute function to get the data
            if(err || !result)
            {
                executefunction(get_sess_data,sessionId);
            }
            // If we have, get it from redis
            else
            {   
                resData = result;
                console.log(resData);
            }
            // settings session data with the result
            sessionData = JSON.parse(resData);
        });
// Execute function with sessionid as value

function executefunction(someFunction, value) {
  someFunction(value);
}
// Getting data from database (using script from Codeigniter)

var get_sess_data = function(response)
{
    var options = {
            host: 'www.example.dev',
            port: 80,
            path: '/index.php/user_session/decrypt?id='+sessionId
        };
    http.get(options, function(result) {
        result.on("data", function(chunk) {
            client.setex('sessions:'+sessionId, 21600, chunk.toString());

        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        });
        result.end(response);
    });
};
```

FYI, I know the code to grab data is working because I can return them if I don't execute the following script "sessionData = JSON.parse(resData);" even if I place it in my if statement.

I'm stuck for hours on it. If anyone have an issue, let me know.

Comment: I think your code is pretty confuse. Could you please comment it and say where are you getting an error?

Besides, you call executefunction, which is undefined, and define execute, which is not called. Is it right?

Comment: Edited with the comment and remove the error from executefunction.

Comment: I am not sure how your code works. just by looking at the get_sess_data, how "path: '/index.php/user_session/decrypt?id='+sessionId" getting the sessionId.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know if I do the right way or not. I just want to check if I have a session or not. If I don't have any, run script and wait to the end of it for a return. You can change everything in the IF statement, this is where my problem is, the sessionId is from an other place, but don't pay attention to it.